# What is tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._OptionsDataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the Transformer code from tensorflow - https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/transformer

In this code, the dataset used is loaded like this -

```
examples, metadata = tfds.load('ted_hrlr_translate/pt_to_en', with_info=True,
                               as_supervised=True)
train_examples, val_examples = examples['train'], examples['validation']
```

When I check the type of train_examples using :

```
type(train_examples)
```

I get the following as output -

```
tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._OptionsDataset
```

Now I just wanted to change some entries of the dataset that is the sentences, but I am not able to as I don't understand the type.

I am able to iterate over it using :

```
for data in train_examples:
    print(data,type(data))
```

And type of data is -

```
<class 'tuple'>
```

Finally what I want is to replace some of these tuples with my own data.
Can someone tell me how to do this or give me some details about this type 
`tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._OptionsDataset`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._OptionsDataset` is just another class extending the base class `tf.compat.v2.data.Dataset` (DatasetV2) which holds `tf.data.Options` along with the original `tf.compat.v2.data.Dataset` dataset (The Portuguese-English tuples in your case).

(`tf.data.Options` operates when you are using streaming functions over your dataset  `tf.data.Dataset.map` or `tf.data.Dataset.interleave`)

**How to view the individual elements?**

I'm sure there are many ways, but one straight way would be to use the iterator in the base class:

Since `examples['train']` is a type of `_OptionsDataset`  here is iterating by calling a method from
`tf.compat.v2.data.Dataset`

```
iterator = examples['train'].__iter__()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
pt = next_element[0]
en = next_element[1]
print(pt.numpy())
print(en.numpy())
```

Here is the output:

```
b'o problema \xc3\xa9 que nunca vivi l\xc3\xa1 um \xc3\xbanico dia .'
b"except , i 've never lived one day of my life there ."
```

**Substituting with your own data:**

Since you've not mentioned what you want to substitute the original dataset with, I'll assume you have a CSV/TSV file of your own specific translations. Then it should be useful to create a separate `tf.compat.v2.data.Dataset` object itself by calling the CSV API to read your CSV file into a dataset:

`tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset`

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/load_data/csv.ipynb

Comment: For the last link, "Notebook not found".

Comment: Updated link: [https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/load_data/csv.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/load_data/csv.ipynb)